# Foxpro not throwing error on arithmetic overflow

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Good day all
I have an issue which is occurring when converting a FoxPro table into MSSQL.

What is happening is, a number was entered into the FoxPro table field, which exceeds the expected value. ( In a 10,2 numeric field a large integer was entered) However despite this, FoxPro still allowed the data to be saved and it is being showed in reports. 
However, when trying to convert said data into MSSQL it causes and error and said value does not get.

I understand that an error is occurring when the number is saved but my question is why is FoxPro allowing this error to go through and even to be displayed when that number is "wrong"

Comment: @AlanB "51862713.80" when I do the insert into a 10,2 field in FoxPro. it shows as '51862713.8'. and doesn't go into SQL. if I change the size too 11,2. it goes thru as normal and is converted into SQL. I have added a lot larger numbers in the 10,2 field and it is not stopping me. Why

Comment: What most people don't know if that a 10,2 numeric field in VFP can actually hold up to 10 digits. That is, it can hold 1234567890. You need to plan accordingly.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor I actually found that out through testing, but I was wondering. why FoxPro does not throw an error when I pass in a greater number. It actually saves it. How is that possible

Comment: Because a N(10,2) field has room for 10 positions. It doesn't care whether you use any of them for decimals or not. Just how it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible because all languages have quirks, and this is just a Visual FoxPro one. You're assuming it will behave in the same way as a strongly-typed, compiled language like C. This behaviour probably dates right back to dBase days and was kept for compatibility.

If you try to insert a value into a numeric field that exceeds the dimensions the rules are:

- Truncate decimal places and round the remaining decimal portion of the field.
- If the value does not fit, store the field contents using scientific notation.
- If the value still does not fit, replace the field contents with asterisks.